# How to read file content and compare string in C language

Tags: c

I have users.txt file and this file content like this

- user1 1223
- user3 7891
- user3 5680

and now I want to read file content and compare with string which is passed as a function argument.

Note - **example:** `userloging` = `"user1 1223"`

```
int sign_in(char *userloging ) {

    char buffer[100];
    FILE *fp = fopen("user.txt", "r");                  
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) {
    
    // in here how can I compare and if found return 1; 
  }

  fclose(fp);

 }
```

Comment: Have you tried searching "c compare strings"?

Comment: I wos many tried search  and I am very new in C language but  Unfortunately   I cant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Comment: vepa, Does your `*userloging` end with `"\n"`?  `buffer` certainly ends with `"\n"`.  Do you want the `'\n'` part of the compare?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at each entire line read from file (as you loop through 1 by 1) to see if within each line there exists a particular *user login*.  Because each entire line may have content other than just the *user login*, two immediate options jump out:

- remove all content from the file line other than content of interest.  (eg `\n`, etc.)  and use [strcmp()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) to compare against the argument `userloging`
- identify an exact match to `userloging` by searching for it as a *sub-string* of the line read from the file using [strstr](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm).

Either method will work.  I prefer `strstr()` as it is adequate for the purpose and simpler to code. (no parsing required to clean up the string.)  Following is an example using `strstr()`:

Edited to use `userloging` input argument...

```
int sign_in(char *userloging ) 
{
    char buffer[100];
    int status = 0;//add this, see why below
    FILE *fp = fopen("user.txt", "r");                  
    if(fp)(//always test to make sure successful open occurred.
    {
        while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) {
        {
            if(strstr(buffer, userloging ))
            {
                // printf("Found %s\n", userloging );//optional
                //return 1; //if return here, cannot fclose(fp)
                status = 1;//user login has been found, leave loop and return
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: str_array[3][]    give me erro  is   incomplete type is not allowedC/C++(70)

Comment: @Vepa - it should have been `char str_array[][20] =... ` Anyway, I edited it out  to use your input argument `userloging`.  Insert into your code and make adjustments to fit your needs